# Spring boot (2.2.0.RELEASE<) with spring data rest endpoint not exposed

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring data rest and I have my application deployed on my PC but when I access the url(http://localhost:8080/) the following json is displayed without the method exposed in my repository :

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

Please find below application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@test:test1
spring.datasource.username=dummy
spring.datasource.password=dummy
spring.datasource.driver=class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver


# HikariCP settings
# spring.datasource.hikari.*

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

My repository class is as follows:

```
public interface UsrAccessRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UsrAccess, Long>{


    List<UsrAccess> findByUserId(@Param("userId") String userId);
//  
    List<UsrAccess> findAll();
}
```

When I access the following url http://localhost:8080/findAll a 404 error is thrown.

I used this example as tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro

Any idea what i am missing here please?

Comment: I don't see any Controller code for processing that `/findAll` path, so why did you think that endpoint would work? --- *Hint:* Repository classes are not Controllers.

Comment: ohh even if i have spring-boot-starter-data-rest on classpath i need controller?I have updated my post  with the url i have used as example

Comment: @Andreas when you use [Spring Data REST](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest) then it can automatically expose Spring Data repositories as REST resources and you don't need to write a controller yourself.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I missing the *Data* part. Thought you were asking about normal Spring MVC REST. --- If you read the article closer, you need to add `@RepositoryRestResource` to control the path of the endpoint, otherwise it default to ... hmmm ... `/UsrAccesses` ??

Comment: Can you try to add [@Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html) annotation to `UsrAccessRepository`?

Comment: I try to add http://localhost:8080/UsrAccesss and repository it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Your `UsrAccessRepository.java` must be in the same package-tree than your main class (annotated by `@SpringBootApplication`).

By default Spring-Data-Rest only scan for repository-interfaces in- and under the main class's package.

If your repository is an other package then use `@ComponentScan`